# Writing list to excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Newer to Python, brand new to openpyxl - I have a large text file that I used regexs to extract the data I need - now I need to write that data to an excel file with openpyxl. The text file is a network address translation (NAT) table which looks like

```
src_adtr:10.20.30.40 dst_adtr:185.50.40.50 src_adtr_translated:70.60.50.40 dst_adtr_translated:99.44.55.66
```

These four elements would be one row of the excel file (I have about 500 rows that need to be written).

When I run the code, I do not get any errors, but it also does nothing - how can I correct this?

```
import re
import openpyxl

with open("NAT-table.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

source = re.findall(r':src_adtr\s+.*\s+.*\s+:Name\s+[\(](.*)', text)
dest = re.findall(r':dst_adtr\s+.*\s+.*\s+:Name\s+[\(](.*)', text)
source_adtr = re.findall(r':src_adtr_translated.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+:Name\s+[\(](.*)', text)
dest_adtr = re.findall(r':dst_adtr_translated\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s*\s+.*\s+.*\s.*\s+:Name\s+[\(](.*)', text)
firewall = re.findall(r'\w+LINT\d+(?!_)', text) #'\w' includes the '_'(underscore) char

natRules = list(zip(source, dest, source_adtr, dest_adtr, firewall))
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('NAT-table.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
for i in range(2, sheet.max_row):
    for k in range(1, 5):
        for t in natRules:
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=k).value = natRules[i][k]
        #sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value = i

wb.save('NAT-table.xlsx')
```

Comment: Do you need to load an existing workbook ?  wb.workbook()  then wb.save(filename) should suffice https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#saving-to-a-file

Comment: I loaded a workbook in which I have titles on the coulmns in which I need populated, but I need the data (four IP address) written to the file

Comment: I suspect you might want to use Python's `csv` module to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data does not match you regular expressions, so `natRules` is empty.  So there is nothing to write.  *I think*.  I say this because it is difficult to tell from your question.

So, since there is no working sample data, it is hard to say exactly where you went wrong.  I will point out that this part:

```
for t in natRules:
    sheet.cell(row=i, column=k).value = natRules[i][k]
```

iterates on `natRules`, but makes no use of `t`.  And in fact sets the cell multiple times.

**Test Code:**

Here is a chunk of test code, which uses your basic loop, and succeeds in writing an `xlsx` file.  Suggest you could slowly modify this to look like your code, but with your data and see where it stops working.

```
data = [list('abcd'), list('efgh')]
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
for i, line in enumerate(data):
    for k, val in enumerate(line):
        sheet.cell(row=i+2, column=k+1).value = val
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Shouldn't your first sentence be a negative?

Comment: @CharlieClark  :-)  Thanks.